# Changing the MAC address for a USB WWAN modem from ICE.net (D-50)

Tags: usb, modem, wwan

Anyone know how I can change the MAC address on a D-50 USB modem from ICE net?

Answer (score 0):

What OS?  In Windows if the driver supports it it's usually done on the properties on the device within Device Manager.  You may see it as "Hardware Address".